# Nginx + nodejs app location

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-location

it's very short question, but i'm overwhelmed. I need nodejs app run under domain.com/nodeapp/.

The problem is - it works correct if i write domain name like: `domain.name/nodeapp/` so when i'm go to `domain.name/nodeapp` - corrupted version loads.

I need nginx to redirect correctly to location with `/nodeapp/`

Now i'm using next config:

```
location /nodeapp {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:20100;
                rewrite ^/nodeapp/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; }
```

How can i do it correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do

```
location /nodeapp {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:20100;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```